# How to in kivy make labels go to the next line if the window size is not big enough

Tags: python, android, user-interface, kivy, label

'''

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

class MyGrid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):# handle as many can com in **kwargs
        super(MyGrid, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 1
        self.add_widget(Label(text="Super long textSuper long textSuper long textSuper long textSuper long textSuper long textSuper long textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper long text"))
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

'''

Up above is my code and when I run the code the text is out of the window:
[image]
So Is there any way I can move the text to the next line if it crosses the windows geometry.

Any suggestions will help thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [text_size](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.label.html#kivy.uix.label.Label.text_size) attribute, like this:

```
self.add_widget(Label(text_size=(500, None), text="Super long textSuper ...
```

Another way is to use kivy language to set up bindings that adjust the `text_size` as the window size changes:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

kv = '''
<MyLabel>:
    size_hint: 0.5, 0.5
    text_size: self.size
'''

class MyLabel(Label):
    pass


class MyGrid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):# handle as many can com in **kwargs
        super(MyGrid, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 1
        self.add_widget(MyLabel(text="Super long textSuper long textSuper long textSuper long textSuper long textSuper long textSuper long textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper textSuper long text"))


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Builder.load_string(kv)
        return MyGrid()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

This code sets `text_size` to always follow the widget `size` in the `MyLabel` class. Using `kv` sets up a binding so that the `text_size` will change as the widget `size` changes.

Comment: It does solve a part of it but it when you resize the window the text  doesn't go to the next line.

Comment: See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't it's not possible in kivy.
Though its possible in tkinter

Comment: See updated answer